# Separation of simple content vs form population view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to work out the best direction when implementing view models that populate forms against simple display data.

This will be shared across a website, facebook app, iframe and will have different views to suit layout.

Example of a simple view model for displaying billing address info.

```
public class BillingAddressVm
{
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public string CountryName;
}
```

Example of a form view model for populating billing address form.

```
public class BillingAddressFormVm
{
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int CountryId;
    public List<Country> Countries;
}
```

Is it better to keep these almost identical View Models separate or should I combine them and not populate parts of the model like the `List<Country>`? If there is a change in naming conventions, would it better to keep it as one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on several things, but mostly: do you use the *form view* often?

If you don't use one particular view that often, it might not be worth the time and effort to add additional properties to your views (all of them, to keep things consistent). You can simply set the populating properties in `ViewBag`. Either way, you still need to get the data from somewhere and store it in another place.

Another issue would be *semantics*. In your particular example, it makes no sense to have an entire list of countries in an object which references one element in that list.

The only strong reason I see for adding such a property would be having full Intellisense support inside the view. In the end, it might just be a matter of personal preferences.

Edit:
I'm just now noticing the last 2 sentences of your question. I would definitely not use two separate models (classes) just because I need to carry some data. This just duplicates existing code and does not bring any concrete improvement. Moreover, it introduces overhead. I presume that the data comes from a database and it gets loaded in your business object `BillingAddressVm`; afterwards you need to copy this object in a new `BillingAddressFormVm`, just for having a container where to store the list of countries. You already have such a container, the `ViewBag`, an using it you don't have to duplicate your business object.

Comment: Yes. Forgot to mention that this will be used across different applications. Eg. Website, facebook app, iframe. I want each `ViewModel` to be specific to it's use and there are multiple people working on this. The reason for the list is to populate a `DropDownList` of Countries.

Comment: I don't think that this is really an issue. Basically you're doing the same thing: sending data to be processed. The data gets there, whether with your model or trough `ViewBag`. As I mentioned, I don't think that it makes semantical sense. If you use these countries in several places, maybe it will be better to make a `CounstriesService` which will _serve_ your list.

Comment: That's where I get confused by your statment about semantics. My ViewModel Mapper is referencing my `CountryService` to map the data to the view model. I couldn't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Do you carry a list of countries in your wallet just because your ID references a particular country?

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I hope it helped. To sum all of it up, if you don't create two almost identically classes, I think it comes down to personal preferences. If you do have to have two classes which differ just by properties used to populate components, I don't think it's good practice (it almost never is good practice to duplicate code).